# Stripping out all brackets from a string - Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, split, brackets

If I want to split this string into an array and strip out all brackets but only want to split in the dash how would I do it.

```
$ADUser = "Offline - Server (Win2012)"
This string could potentially be:  "Offline | Server (Win2012)" 
With pipe split!

###This:  
$userdesc = ($ADUser -split ' *[-|] *') -notmatch '[?@]' -replace '^\(|\)$'

##results as:  
Offline   
Server (Win2012

##But I need this:  
Offline  
Server Win2012

##I have tried this to no avail:  
($ADUser -split ' *[-|] *') -notmatch '[?@]' -replace '^\(|\)$|^\s*\(\$'
```

Any clues or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to escape the brackets, so: `-replace '\(|\)'`

Comment: `("Offline - Server (Win2012)" -replace '[)(]' -split '-').trim()`

Comment: @nimizen  - I have that in the first line of code:  -replace '^\(|\)$' - Resulting with the ( mid string between Server and Win2012.   I need that string to be clean of brackets.

Comment: @Olaf If I am splitting the string "Offline - Server (Win2012)" already into an array the brackets need to be removed from the second word in the array - Server (Win2012

Comment: You may update your question with more precise information what exactly  you need. My suggestion produces the result you posted as expected result. ;-)

Comment: `("Offline | Server (Win2012)" -replace '[)(]' -split '-|\|').trim()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
($ADUser -split "\s*[|-]\s*") | ?{ $_ -notmatch '[?@]' } | %{ $_ -replace '[()]' }
```

That is

- `($ADUser -split "\s*[|-]\s*")` - splits with a `|` or `-` chars enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `?{ $_ -notmatch '[?@]' }`  - discards all items not containing `?` and `@`
- `%{ $_ -replace '[()]' }` - removes the parentheses.

Comment: I need to maintain additional criteria  Here:    ```-split ' *[-|] *') -notmatch '[?@]'

Comment: This does the job but it's not complete.  I need to maintain all criteria in my code.

Comment: This has now been answered.